# Eliminate div shifting on hover

Tags: html, css

I'm attempting to have a div background image change to a new image on-hover, and it's working correctly, however, when the image is swapped it shifts slightly. Is there a way to eliminate this shifting effect?

```
.temptext {
    background: url("my-img1.png");
    background-size: 35% 33%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 33%;
    margin-top: 38%;
}

.temptext:hover {
    background: url("my-img2.png");
    background-size: 35% 33%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position-x: 3.6px;
    background-position-y: -.35px;
}
```

I've attempted using background-position-x/y to specify the pixel shift, which eliminated it almost entirely, however I've now manually gotten down to the millionths in decimal places and it's still shifting every-so-slightly. Any advice or alternative solutions?

Comment: do you have any whitespace in that image?

Comment: Yes. I actually just discovered in photoshop that the images weren't identically situated despite having the same canvas pixel area. I'm about to try swapping in the new image with the adjusted pixel locations.

Comment: glad to be of help

Comment: Unfortunately the modified images didn't change the shift. Good suggestion though, thank you.

Comment: can you create a fiddle with temporary images from placehold.it and show the issue

Comment: Edited with fiddle. Actually I just changed the background-position which was incorrect and it works correctly in the fiddle. This is maddening. Give me a moment.

Comment: if you remove the background position then it works on the fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/karthick6891/rc9q40pt/2/

Answer (score 0):

You should combine the two images into a single sprite to avoid the flicker.

Comment: I'm not sure this will work for a div background image swap? While I've never had to work with sprites before, it looks like they're used to display a combination of two different images as a single image. I could be wrong as I'm basing this off less than five minutes of google searches. If I am, could you point me to a tutorial you recommend for performing something similar to the image swap using sprites?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured out what the problem was. Because the pixel dimensions of the two images were exactly the same (1600x750), the image was shifting itself because it read it as 'bigger' than the initial image. When I changed the on-hover image canvas size to one pixel smaller than the original image, the shift was eliminated. This is apparently a problem with text that changes font-size and similar effects when hovered over as well.